# Can you refuse services to businesses you deem unethical?

Tags: european-union, netherlands

As a business owner, is it within my rights to refuse to sell products to other businesses that I personally view as unethical, such as Facebook, due to their alleged questionable or harmful practices?

Is it possible that this decision could result in any negative consequences for my business, such as legal issues? Are there any laws or regulations that may prohibit me from making this type of decision based on my personal beliefs about the ethics of a particular company?

Edit: As a follow up question, how would one go about doing this, would it be to include such information in terms and conditions, or perhaps a statement outlining policies on ethical business practices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are the CEO of a public company, this might be a problem if it causes less profits for the shareholders. They could fire you if your actions cost them money.

If you are the owner of a business, then the CEO of your company (you) can do anything legal that all your shareholders (you) agree with. Nobody can force your company to deal with anyone, especially with no business, except for existing contracts or if there is illegal discrimination. Now all this is not “your personal opinion” but “the ceo running the company according to the wishes of the shareholders”.

You are allowed legally to discriminate against a company whose business practices you don’t like.

You have to do nothing, just don’t deal with them. If Facebook sends you a million dollar order, just don’t accept it. Make sure that no sales contract is created.

It is remotely possible that you have problems if such a decision causes you to go bankrupt and you can’t pay your taxes or debt, like a debtor could claim you could have paid your debt and want your personal money instead of your broke company’s money.

Comment: Note that this can potentially run afoul of non-discrimination laws, if the claimed "unethical behavior" encompasses certain protected characteristics.